# Random address setting in bluetooth low energy

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

For random address setting in the controller by the host in LE, is it mandatory to set the address type also by some means? if address type is not set by the host, can controller set the new address type itself for sending packets over the air?

Comment: Did you read 6.B.1.3.2 of the [Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=286439) ?

Answer (score 0):

You set the type of address you want to use when you call LE Set Advertising Parameters, LE Set Scan Parameters or LE Create Connection command.